# matplotlib plots fail silently in vscode but work from the python interpreter in the same environment

Tags: matplotlib, visual-studio-code

Until today, matplotlib was working with vscode. TOday I updated vscode to the latest version and found that plots don't work. They work from the same virtual environment using the python interpreter but not from vscode. I rolled back to earlier versions of both matplotlib and vscode, but it still doesn't work. Here is my code to plot:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2],[3,4])
plt.show()
```

The version of vscode is 1.53.2 and the version of matplotlib is 3.3.4

If I call plt.savefig, it saves the figure. It just doesn't display interactively.
I have tried this with multiple virtual envioronments and multiple vscode workspaces, all of which worked before today.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode doesn't see my DISPLAY environment variable on my Linux system, so it is running headless. I can make plots work by giving the command "export DISPLAY=:0" in the vscode terminal window. I would like to have this happen automatically but I don't know how to make that happen.

The way I discovered this was by inserting "matplotlib.use("TKAgg")" in my python script. This elicited a message saying that I was running headless.

The way I found the correct value for DISPLAY was to examine that variable in a terminal window outside of vscode.

When I went to report this on the vscode Github page, I found the suggestion to disable all extensions. When I do that, I don't have to set DISPLAY. I then went and reenabled all extensions, and plotting still works, so it seems the fix was to disable and reenable all extensions.